# NoReverseMatch Error, even though everything should be set

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

https://pastebin.com/EBfq1SRL

Getting this error, Even though this is how my views and URL's are setup:

```py
class MyProfile(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profiletabs/user-profile.html'
    extra_context = {'profile': 'active-page'}
```

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('tags', views.TagViewSet)
router.register('bots', views.BotViewSet)

app_name = 'profile'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MyProfile.as_view(), name='my_profile'),
    path('settings/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception "NoReverseMatch" is raised when the URL you’re reversing doesn’t exist.
The probleme come surely in your templates when you tried to retrive some urls;
to avoid that you can check if the url exist before;
like that:

```
  {% url 'url-name' as the_url %}
  {% if the_url %}
     <a href="{{ the_url }}">Hello</a>
  {% endif %}
```

[see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: Thats the issue though you can clearly see the 'my_profile' url is listed in the URL patterns, so just running a testcase to ignore the page i'm trying to load won't fix the issue, it will just ignore it. and the error only came up after i put the Router in.